# How many solutions are possible to this equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, binomial-coefficients, diophantine-equations, multinomial-coefficients

Given
$$A+2B+3C=N
$$
where $N$ is a given positive integer.

$A ,B,C\in\mathbb{N}$ vary from $0$ to $\infty$.

How many solutions will be there to this equation?

Comment: Please try and format your questions using $\LaTeX$ notation, and avoid non-standard abbreviations.

Comment: $N+3-1\choose{3-1}$ , it isn't possible I suppose?

Comment: Are $A,B,C$ also *integers*?

Comment: Yes A,B,C are intergers

Comment: @Berci ,ABC are integrs

Comment: @Inceptio: Answer for N=8 is 10

Comment: Take $2B=x_1, 3B=x_2$. Then you get $x_1=(0,1,..N)$, Now choose every 2 out of it, since $x_1$ is even. And similarly for $x_2$.

Comment: @Inceptio:    Any formula you could find?

Comment: I'm trying to deduce one!

Comment: @Inceptio: I think we can multiply multinomial here

Comment: @I think the answer is (n+3)*(n+3)/12

Comment: @user1907531 I don't think that's right. For $n = 1$ that would give $4/3$, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: Seems to be related to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/334972/ ...

Answer (score 3):

It appears to be sequence [A001399](http://oeis.org/A001399) at the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences, where the simple formula $${\rm round}{(n+3)^2\over12}$$ is given, along with lots of interpretations, links, references, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Let $X=C, Y=B+C, Z=A+B+C$, then this is equivalent to finding the number of non-negative integer solutions to $X+Y+Z=N$ s.t. $X \leq Y \leq Z$.

First ignore the restriction on $X, Y, Z$. In total we have $\binom{N+2}{2}$ solutions.

The number of solutions with $Y=Z$ is just the number of non-negative integer solutions to $2Y \leq N$, giving $\lfloor \frac{N}{2} \rfloor+1$. By symmetry we get the same number of solutions for $X=Y, X=Z$.

The number of solutions for $X=Y=Z$ is 1 if $3 \mid N$ and 0 otherwise. We can represent this as $1-\lceil \frac{N}{3}-\lfloor \frac{N}{3} \rfloor \rceil$.

The number of solutions with exactly 2 variables equal is thus $3[(\lfloor \frac{N}{2} \rfloor+1)-(1-\lceil \frac{N}{3}-\lfloor \frac{N}{3} \rfloor \rceil)]$.

Now going back to the problem, each solution where $X<Y<Z$ corresponds to 6 solutions where $X, Y, Z$ are distinct. Each solution with $X \leq Y \leq Z$ and exactly 2 of them equal corresponds to 3 solutions where exactly 2 of them equal but without the condition $X \leq Y \leq Z$.

We thus get:

\begin{align}
& \frac{\binom{N+2}{2}-3(\lfloor \frac{N}{2} \rfloor+1)+2(1-\lceil \frac{N}{3}-\lfloor \frac{N}{3} \rfloor \rceil)}{6} \\
& +\frac{3(\lfloor \frac{N}{2} \rfloor+1)-3(1-\lceil \frac{N}{3}-\lfloor \frac{N}{3} \rfloor \rceil)}{3} +(1-\lceil \frac{N}{3}-\lfloor \frac{N}{3} \rfloor \rceil) \\
& =\frac{\binom{N+2}{2}+3(\lfloor \frac{N}{2} \rfloor+1)+2(1-\lceil \frac{N}{3}-\lfloor \frac{N}{3} \rfloor \rceil)}{6}
\end{align}

Comment: This is what I was tryna do(Use greatest int func).:). +1 Great solution.

Answer (score 1):

The result will be equal to the coeeficient of $x^{n}$ in $(x+x^{2}+x^{3}+\dots)(x^{2}+x^{4}+\dots)(x^{3}+x^{6}+\dots)$